# How to connect Firebase with Admob?

Tags: firebase, admob

I tried to connect my project to Admob, but it shows like:

> You don't have access to Firebase from this AdMob account.
> Another user on this AdMob account is the only account user with access to Firebase. Please ask that user directly to provide you with access to Firebase via the Firebase console.

I alos found that

> The user who created the first Firebase link is the only user who can
> create new links between AdMob and Firebase apps.

However, the situation is no one knows who is the first person did the connection. How could I treat with this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I found out, that the first user, who did the first Firebase link was the same user, who had created an Admob account.
In the **Settings** => **Account Information** I found Google Ads customer ID. Then I identified that user in the Google Ads setup "Access and Security" section.
I grant him access to a Firebase project & Google Analytics.
Only after that, I was able to link the Firebase project to Admob under that user.
I don't know how to deal with this if the first user is deleted.

Comment: Could be more clear.